# Suddenly Debug tab shows nothing and Logcat also disappeard?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, debugging, logcat

I'm using Android stuido in MacBook Pro with M1 chip laptop. Suddenly debug tab shows nothig and logcat also disappeared I could not see any logs. And the issue not only this project, this problem remains in all of my project. I tried all solutions from the internet nothing helps me.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to run release version and forget to put back to debug?

Comment: No brother @HKN

Comment: @HKN bro can u upvot to impro this question